# Buttons to go to the first and last post in blogger,

Tags: blogger

I would need to know how to create a button to go to the first and last post in blogger, but it doesn't work, I think it's because I put it next to the **next post** and **previous post** buttons and in that area, I think it doesn't work.

I have tried this:

```
<b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'>
     <a expr:href='data:post.url'>
         First
     </a>
</b:if>
```